# How do I get rid of this message in VSCode terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am new to VSCode and
Currently I have a problem with VSCode with Python interpreter and every time I try to run the code I get this message in the terminal even when I ask for something simple like

```
print ('123')
```

**instead I get this message:**

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\username\Desktop\username> & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python/python.exe" "c:/Users/username/Desktop/prog/bot.py"

PS C:\Users\Username\Desktop\prog>

Does anyone know what's going on?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What happens when you run this on the terminal?

Comment: That's not a message, that is Powershell starting up, and then PowerShell running your python code. It's a command, and assuming you've saved your `bot.py` file, it should print the output.

Comment: VSC is not a Python REPL